# Animating several objects randomly moving across the surface of another object

Tags: animation

Basically what I need is to make simple spheres move across the surface of another different objects - like another sphere for example. I tried using hair particle system to place spheres onto the surface of an object but there seems for me to be no way to animate them moving using the particle system. I searched the internet to find an answer but found nothing.

[image: This is an image of sphere which hast to move across the surface of another object]

I also need to be able to animate them moving not only across primitive objects like another sphere but more complex ones - like the one on screenshot below
[image: An example of an object across the surface of which spheres should be moving]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two objects: your shape (are they $s$ and $p$ atomic orbitals?) to generate particles, and a *fattened* version of it to contain them.

Result:

[image: workbench]

(workbench)

[image: eevee]

(eevee)

### Procedure

#### Emitter object

On your main shape, add a *Particle System*. Things to change with respect to the defaults:

1. *Emission* > "*Frame End*" must be 1 (all particles emitted at the beginning of time), "*Lifetime*" as long as you like
2. *Emission* > *Source* > "*Emit From*" should be "*Volume*"
3. *Velocity* > "*Normal*" should be 0
4. *Physics* > *Forces* > "*Brownian*" to some value around 3
5. *Field Weight* > "*Gravity*" to 0
6. *Render* > "*Render As*" to "*Object*" (then select a UVSphere to duplicate)

#### Container object

Duplicate your main object, and remove the Particle System from the duplicate.

In *Edit Mode*, use the *Shrink/Fatten* tool (you can find it using *Search* or in the <kbd>T</kbd> toolshelf) and fatten it a bit. Then invert its normals: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> so that they point *in*wards.

In the *Physics* panel, activate *Collision*. Default parameters work well.

Since this is an helper object, you may want to restrict its *render visibility* in the Outliner, and to make its *Viewport Display* > *Display as Wires* in the Object properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'll try it in a moment. And you guessed right - these are atomic orbitals

Comment: That has worked pretty well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Excelent solution! I'd add a collision to emitter too, because they penetrate it on the animation. (maybe it would need another helper collider, this time shrinked). <offtop> it remainded me the effect from the first The Lawnmower Man movie :-) </offtop>

Comment: @mechanic the question, as I understood it, specifically asks that the particles move *across* the surface

Comment: @Nicola Sap, sorry for that, I just missed it. Anyway, now I know what are those S and P orbitals :-)